# How to use bean directly by ApplicationContext instant in Spring

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext, spring-bean

I'm trying to access `UserService` class by using `ApplicationContext` in Spring.

This is my controller class

```
package com.dilini.controller;

import com.dilini.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    UserService userService = (UserService) applicationContext.getBean(UserService.class);

    @RequestMapping("hi")
    @ResponseBody
    public String hi() {
        return "User count is " + userService.findNumberOfUsers();
    }

}
```

And this is my Service class

```
package com.dilini.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public interface UserService {

    public int findNumberOfUsers();
}
```

And this is my service implementation class.

```
package com.dilini.service.impl;

import com.dilini.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service("UserService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Override
    public int findNumberOfUsers() {
        return 50;
    }
}
```

When I'm running the application I get a `Null point exception`.

```html
Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)



Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloController' defined in file [C:\Users\dilin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mvcquick\target\mvcquick-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\com\dilini\controller\HelloController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.dilini.controller.HelloController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:535)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.dilini.controller.HelloController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:535)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Root Cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.dilini.controller.HelloController.<init>(HelloController.java:25)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:535)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can you please tell me why is this happening?

Didn't I use the annotations correctly. Please help me.

Thank you.

**Edit**

I'm following in a Spring CookBook tutorial. I accessed `Bean` using `Autowired` directly to `UserService` instant.

```
@Autowired
UserService userService;

@RequestMapping("hi")
@ResponseBody
public String hi() {
return "nb of users: " + userService.findNumberOfUsers();
}
```

Now I'm trying this `ApplicationContext` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do that by letting Spring inject the bean in your class. For example, using `@Autowired`

```
@Autowired
UserService userService;
```

Then the userService variable will correctly reference your UserService bean.

Edit:
If you want to specifically get the bean from applicationContext, then you have to put this code `UserService userService = (UserService) applicationContext.getBean(UserService.class);` inside of your hi() method, to make sure that Spring has created and injected all necessary dependencies before you call it.

Comment: Yes. I used that method before. Now I'm trying to use applicationcontext in spring to access the bean. (I'm following a tutorial)

Comment: Have you tried putting `UserService userService = (UserService) applicationContext.getBean(UserService.class);` inside of hi()? Maybe it is being executed before a UserService bean has been created, and Spring doesn't know in which order to create beans because you are not autowiring it.

Comment: hey it worked. How the hell that happened? While it wasn't working in outside of the method?

Comment: I think that it has something to do with the order in which Spring creates the beans. When you inject via autowired, Spring determines in which order it has to create all necessary beans so all dependencies are satisfied. In your case it just didn't expect you to require the bean so it couldn't prepare.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. If you updated your answer to this. Then I can accept it.

Comment: Thank you @pippilongstocking

Answer (score 1):

Try to move `UserService userService = (UserService) applicationContext.getBean(UserService.class);` code into the `hi()` method like:

```
 @RequestMapping("hi")
    @ResponseBody
    public String hi() {
        return "User count is " + (UserService) applicationContext.getBean(UserService.class).findNumberOfUsers();
    }
```

It can be useful if you want to inject prototype bean in the singleton bean

Comment: Can you please explain to me what is the  prototype bean and singleton bean in here? Thanks

Comment: @pippilongstocking It bean scopes :). If the bean has **singleton** scope it means you will get the **same** object every time you inject it. If the bean has **prototype** scope it means you will get the **different** object every time you inject it. See more details [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm)